# Fast test for existence of string in SWIFT

Tags: string, swift, dictionary, lookup

I have a list of 5.000.000 words from a dictionary. And I have to check all combinations of some randomly combined characters with that list. Let's assume I have a (generated) word "chair". I need to check as fast as possible, if this is in the list. I don't have an overiew how many combinations from the characters I can build, but I think it will also get more than a million.

Any idea how to do it? Using a build-in Dictionary would give me an indexed access, right? But searching in this large dictionary would also be time consuming right?

Because the dictionary is static and will be imported at application start, while the set of characters will change a little bit over time, a static optimized structure for the dictionary would be possible.
Could bitmap operations used here? Or nested dictionaries? Special Lookup tables?

Comment: Have you already written a solution using `Dictionary` and determined it's not performant enough? If so, can you post this solution? If not, you might want to try it before writing your own data structure.

Comment: I'm just starting. Before running the wrong way, I want to make sure, that the approach could be successful. So I will start with the simple solution to put everything into a Dictionary.